# Can't get Marionette Routing to Work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, marionette

I can't get Marionette routing to work

```
@Arc = do(Backbone, Marionette) ->
  App = new Marionette.Application

  API =
    listContacts: ()->
      console.log "from listContacts"

  class MyRouter extends Marionette.AppRouter
    appRoutes:
      "notes" : "listContacts"
    controller: API

  App.router = new MyRouter()


  App.on 'start', ->
    console.log "in on start"
    if Backbone.history
      Backbone.history.start(pushStart: true)

  App

console.log "before"
@Arc.start()
console.log "after"
```

visiting `localhost:3000/notes` does not log the message `from listContacts`. If I turn `pushState: false` visiting `localhost:3000/#notes` does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `Backbone.history.start(pushState: true)`, not `pushStart`.